# show int variables in a AlertDialog and show as message

Tags: java, android, integer, android-alertdialog

I need to display in a AlertDialog the following message and show it. using this code I already have done it on this way :

```
AlertDialog dialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.pic_time +
        " qntpic" +//This is one variable i must call from a .java called PreviewCamera
        R.string.pic +
        "time" +//This is one variable i must call from a .java called PreviewCamera
        R.string.time);
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null );
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show()
```

but i don't know how to proceed to call this variables, i try already some methods but no results.

This variables are int, and private on PreviewCamera.

Comment: use `getResources().getString(R.string.pic_time)` etc.

Comment: Why don't you open R.java and take a look inside?  Then you will understand.

Comment: @Simon I try already, but don't understand that clearly. But thanks for the tip, i will keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: Each resource, including strings, is stored with a unique integer ID.  R.java just creates a static constant with a name taken from the resource so that instead of having to know the number, and type it in, you just use R.string.pic_time.  Instead of using `getResources().getString(R.string.pic_time)` you could use `getResources().getString(4147263398242)` - or whatever ID your string has.

Answer (score 1):

Using the information that you guys give it to me, this appear.
This is the solution if maybe someone find the same problem as me

```
    AlertDialog dialog; AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.pic_time) + 
Integer.parseInt(bdl.getqntpic()) +
    getResources().getString(R.string.pic)+
    Integer.parseInt(bdl.getTime()) +
    getResources().getString(R.string.time)); 

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null ); dialog = builder.create(); dialog.show(); }
```

Is that right? it kind of works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.pic_time` return the id of the resource. 
If you want the value of the resource, you have to use `getResources().getString(R.string.pic_time)` for a String or `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.time)` for an Integer.

The Integer can be converted to String by use : `String.valueOf(yourInt`)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing .xml variables and .java variables.

**.XML** variables are get with getResources().getString(R.string.pic_time) or getResources().getInt(R.int.pic_time). They are defined inside a .xml file (named only with lowercase letters and underscore) under a folder "res/values". They are set at compiletime and cannot(/shouldn't?) be changed at runtime (afaik).

**.java** variables are variables set by your java code, inside classes. They are get with references. When you call `System.out.println(pic_time);`, you get the value of your variable "pic_time" thanks to its reference in memory.

Example : the class `MainActivity` will get the variable "pic_time" from the class `A_Class` : 
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Accueil extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        A_Class mySecondClass = new A_Class();

        int myInt = mySecondClass.getPicTime();

        System.out.println(myInt);
    }
}
```

**A_Class.java**

```
public class A_Class
{
    private int pic_time;

    public A_Class()
    {
        pic_time = 50;
    }

    public int getPicTime()
    {
        return pic_time;
    }
}
```